# Android Maps API v2 : The import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.IndoorBuilding cannot be resolved

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, indoor-positioning-system, google-indoor-maps

I tried to make demo application of google indoor maps but i am not able to access some interfaces and some classes.

I added google play services project as a project library in my sample application. you can see in image all other classes and interface i am able to access but not about indoor related. Is there any problem?

Please help me, any help would be appreciated.

```
Error : "The import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.IndoorLevel cannot be resolved"
```

Here is the image of error.

[image]

Comment: Please help. This is really annoying.

Comment: Have you had your Google Play Services installed?

Comment: @ztan Yes installed thats why other import does not make any problem, only indoorbuilding related stuff i am not able to resolved.

Comment: which version you installed? You might want to try the newest version 6.5

Comment: @Ztan : Let me Check, how can i check that? Can you please tell me. Its showing 22 in front of SDK manager.

Comment: @ztan : Problem is about version of goolge play service. On my laptop i have two sdk in both sdk google play services jar contains different class.In one google play services library project it contains LocationClient Class and in one it is not contains IndoorBuilding and other classes. But in my sdk manager there is no update for google play services. How can i check which is latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newest Google Play Services should be version 22, you can check in SDK manager. The `LocationClient` should already been deprecated. So If you have the newest version, `LocationClient` should not be contained.

You should use the Google Play Service Project file in this location:

```
<YOUR_ANDROID_SDK_LOCATION>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/
```

(The jar file is in:`<YOUR_ANDROID_SDK_LOCATION>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/libs/`)

I included the newest play service jar file in [this Google Drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw7fO7OOjpacclBfZmhaVVZfdGs/view?usp=sharing).

You should follow the the steps here: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup to setup your Google Play Services correctly.

Alternately, you can install the `Google Repository` from the SDK manager.